# Shell Script read CSV file (Skip Header)

Tags: shell

I have below SH script which reads test.csv file but it is not printing command what I am expecting. Please help

```
read header
while IFS="," read -r user role
do
    echo "btp assign security_role-collection $role --to-user $user"
    
done
} < test.csv
```

test.csv file records as below

```
user,role
test1@yahoo.com,testrole1
test2@yahoo.com,testrole2
```

Results what I am getting is:

```
 --to-user test1@yahoo.comollection testrole1
 --to-user test2@yahoo.comollection testrole2
btp assign security_role-collection  --to-user
```

but I am expecting below results instead. What am I doing wrong ?

```
btp assign security_role-collection  testrole1 --to-user test1@yahoo.com
btp assign security_role-collection  testrole2 --to-user test2@yahoo.com
```

Comment: Your input file has dos line endings. Remove them.

Comment: You also might have an empty line at the end.

Comment: Removing line ending has removed last line of output but still it does not explain why $"btp assign security_role_collection and role value is not printed on screen and email is printed first.

Answer (score 1):

When you read this line `test1@yahoo.com,testrole1` and the line has `\r\n` line endings, the value of `$role` is `testrole1\r`

The string you create looks like

```
btp assign security_role-collection testrole1\r --to-user test1@yahoo.com
.............................................^^
```

And when you print it, the carriage return moves the cursor to column 1.

You want

```sh
{
read header
while IFS="," read -r user role
do
    echo "btp assign security_role-collection ${role%$'\r'} --to-user $user"
    # ........................................^^^^^^^^^^^^^
done
} < test.csv
```

or

```sh
{
read header
while IFS="," read -r user role
do
    echo "btp assign security_role-collection $role --to-user $user"
done
} < <(sed 's/\r$//' test.csv)
# ..^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working.

Comment: Or `IFS=$',\r'`